# Unable to view the HTML source code of a web page

Tags: javascript, html

Could you please post the HTML source code of this web page:

http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test3.html

I just cannot figure out how to retrieve it..

Comment: Click "Cancel" and then go back. Then you can use the browser's View Source.

Comment: @Evan Chrome doesn't let me go back.

Comment: Vidas: Hmm. Never heard that one. I had no problem with Safari.

Comment: @Evan I just tested in FF 3.6, IE9 beta, Opera 11, Chrome 8 and Safari 5. Result: Safari is the only browser which lets you go back and view the source code. Good to know that `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) or switch off JavaScript.

P.S.: The magic word is `"wen"`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use "View source" option from tool menu in browser.

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var password;
var pass1="wen";
password = prompt('Whats The Magic Word?',' ');
if (password === pass1)
    alert('That Is Correct!');
else
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="ImageBook()">
TEST
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The prompt window blocks the browser. I cannot click on anything other then the prompt itself. You must have JavaScript disabled or something.

Comment: I never disable javascript :) Tool menu ordinary is on top left part of the browser. I noticed that right click didn't work;

Comment: You must be using Opera :) Firefox, Chrome and Safari block the browser and the menu cannot be accessed while the prompt is active.

Comment: I can confirm that. Also, I like the new design of the prompt window :)

Comment: You can prefix the entire url with "view-source:" in Chrome to automatically view the source view.

Answer (score 1):

"Right-Click + Save Link/Target As..." can be helpful sometimes :) There are several methods of doing this.

```
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript"> 
    var password;
    var pass1="wen";
    password = prompt('Whats The Magic Word?',' ');
    if (password === pass1)
        alert('That Is Correct!');
    else
        window.location="SITE-LINK";
    </script>

    </head>

    <body onLoad="ImageBook()">
    TEST


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "right click never fails" is a bold statement. I could imagine several situations where this woldn't work.

Comment: @Tomalak - True. Usually something like it could work a majority of the time, but there are tons of different ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

Either disable JavaScript on your browser, or use some kind of command line tool (e.g curl).

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var password;
var pass1="wen";
password = prompt('Whats The Magic Word?',' ');
if (password === pass1)
    alert('That Is Correct!');
else
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
</script>
</head>           
<body onLoad="ImageBook()">
TEST
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug in firefox and select the script.

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var password;
var pass1="wen";
password = prompt('Whats The Magic Word?',' ');
if (password === pass1)
    alert('That Is Correct!');
else
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
</script>


</head>

                  
<body onLoad="ImageBook()">
TEST
                  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The prompt window block the entire browser. I cannot open Firebug or anything. How did you do it?

Comment: open firebug first, and select the script tab and then load the page.

Comment: The problem is that, while the prompt window is active, I cannot see the code in Firebug, and when I close the prompt, I only see the code for a fractal of a second before I get redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Type in keyboard
Ctrl + U in windows 10